# .reduce returns only one object instead of an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I created my pipe and service. An array of language abbreviations goes to pipe, then pipe calls functions from the site.
This is what it passes as a parameter to `pipe = ["be", "bg", "cs", "da", "de", "el", "en"]`

this is pipe

```
transform(value: any[], kind: string): Observable<string | any>{
        this.customTranslateService.getSortedTranslation(value, kind).subscribe(val => console.log("pipe", val));
        return this.customTranslateService.getSortedTranslation(value, kind);
    }
```

this is my service

```
getSortedTranslation(value: any[], kind: string): Observable<string | any> {
return this.translateService.get(value.map(lang => `gen.glo.lang.${lang}`))
            .pipe(
                switchMap(result => of(Object.entries(result).sort((a, b) => (a > b) ? 1 : -1).reduce((object, [k, v]) => {
                    object['key']=k.split(".").pop();
                    object['value']=v;
                    return object;
                }, {}))),
            );
}
```

is return object: `{key: "en", value: "English"}`

Unfortunately, all the code does not work as it should. My service only returns the last item. So the application returns an error:

```
LanguageSelectionDialogComponent.html:15 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

If I do `console.log` in pipe, it prints the whole object in turn with all the elements, unfortunately only the last one gets to pip and the html file. I have a request for help in finding the cause of this problem and an example solution.

Comment: Please provide the return result of your service.

Comment: provide some fiddler. will help you

Comment: Yes, that's what reduce does. What is the expected output? Also why use `switchMap(() => of(value))` rather than just `map(() => value)`?

Comment: `.sort((a, b) => (a > b) ? 1 : -1)` does not account for equality, so your sorting might mis-order some items.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i used ``switchMap`` because when i try used map(() => of(value)) i get error ``Cannot find name 'map'``. and used ``of`` because without this reduce doesn't return anything to pipe.

Comment: You need to import map as you imported switchMap, and of course it returns a value otherwise it wouldn't return it to of either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do something like the following?

```
const key = k.split(".").pop();
object[key] = v;
return object;
```

It will result in:

```
{
en: 'English',
fr: 'French',
...
}
```

Or if you want an array of objects, then accumulator in reduce should be an array:

```
            .reduce((array, [k, v]) => {
                const object = {};
                object['key']=k.split(".").pop();
                object['value']=v;
                array.push(object)
            }, [])
```

Which will result in:

```
[
{key: 'en', value: 'English'},
{key: 'fr', value: 'French'}
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is what I needed. The only thing i changed is ```array.push(object);
     return array.sort((a, b) => (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : -1);```

Comment: That way you will sort in every iteration, better do a sort on the result of reduce. `.reduce(.........).sort((a, b) => (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : -1)`

Comment: Why do a reduce with an array instead of just a map?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Definitely better.